# Is there a conditional version of $\beta$-VAE?

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes

Pretty straightforward question. I could not find any information on the existence of a "conditional $\beta$-VAE". I'm using CVAE for a regression problem and having trouble balancing KL and MSE losses. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there certainly is. You’d define it by extending the CVAE ELBO objective in the same way that $\beta$-VAE extends the VAE’s ELBO.

Just introduce the $\beta$ coefficient in front of the second term of equation (3) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.09237v1.pdf).